# why is it right to say "a... professionalism"?

Tags: articles, uncountable-nouns

> As jeans-lovers have entered the corporate world they have popularized a casual work look, wearing Jeans as the basic wardrobe ___ laid-back but actually ambitious new professionalism. (From an English test)

Why "of a seemingly" would fit for the blank?　The Oxford dictionary presents the world "professionalism" as uncountable, so isn't it contradictory to the article " a＂？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many (perhaps most) uncountable words can be used as countable when the reference is to a particular instance or type.

Compare:

> *I will drink some wine* (uncountable) with *That is a good wine* (a type, so countable).

> *I feel love* (uncountable) with *I have a love of music* (a type, so countable).

> *We hate injustice* (uncountable) with *An injustice which must be corrected* (a specific instance, so countable).

Here we have *a laid-back but ... ambitious new professionalism* (maybe not strictly a **type** of professionalism, but qualified in the same kind of way) - countable.